# PHP - SOAP Determine the methods present

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client

I have webservice that when opening in the browser displays an xml file. I connected to the webser with these line

```
  $client = new SoapClient("http://XXXXXXXXX/webservice/test?wsdl");
```

printing out the $client will display this:

```
  SoapClient Object
  (
        [_soap_version] => 1
        [sdl] => Resource id #4
  )
```

Now, my question is how do I user some method presnt in the xml file just by viewing the xml file? It is because I want to retrieve and verify some data then manipulate it.

How do I do this? am I doing things right?

PS: just to make things put to context, I am able to access the xml viewing it through the browser. Somehow this is the only thing that was given to me. If it is possible to play around in PHP with only that I would really appreciate the replies.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the name of function, and parameters for that function you can call the func.

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://XXXXXXXXX/webservice/test?wsdl");
$info = $client->__soapCall('Name of function' array('param1' => 1, 'param2' => 2);
```

If you do not know the exact name of parameters this will help

```
var_dump ($client->__getTypes());
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! that's exactly what I need. just to clarify, those inside the parenthesis example. [1] => struct method1 {int id; string username} ... id and username are parameter right?

Comment: Yes, these are the parameters

Comment: Thanks NemanjaLazic really appreciate your reply. My problem now is to retrieve data because it is still returning an error saying "SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Fault occurred while processing." but, as far the question in this thread goes this is good. Thanks. But if you could shed a light on that it would be much appreciated. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: you can try to trace request.
[link](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php)

Answer (score 2):

to get the methods and the parameters

```
    $client = new SoapClient("http://my_exposed_url?wsdl");
    var_dump($client->__getFunctions());    
    var_dump($client->__getTypes());
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the SoapClient documentation on php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

As you can see there is a method for getting the available functions: [`SoapClient::__getFunctions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getfunctions.php)

Comment: Follow up question.. right now when I call it it says "Fault occurred while processing." its probably the parameters. How do I know what are its parameters?

Comment: Wrap the call in a `try...catch` block. SoapFault usually contains the problem.
Also check the WSDL, it contains the parameters for the functions.

Comment: I did it only shows this "SoapClient->__call('webchat', Array)" I still do not know what are those parameter needed for this call. Is there a way by viewing in the XML? if so, how?

Comment: Or read the documentation of the SOAP service you are trying to access?